# Recommended approach for java remote gui implementation

Tags: java, html, multithreading, swing, design-patterns

I have an application that analyzes video streams across multiple threads.

[image]

What would be the best approach getting the information to a gui? Every Task is analyzing a separate video stream. I would like to visualize the work of threads.

I see two ways of dealing with the problem:

1. Remote Swing or JavaFX application
2. Web application

What do I need to implement to realize the visualization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This all depends on your preferences. If you familiar with HTML, you can implement a Web application. If you are familiar with Java, I would suggest you to use JavaFX (if third-party client libs are allowed, or you use Java 8 for implementation) or Swing (in other case).

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets say I prefer a remote java swing application as gui modul. What would be the recommended approach getting the visualization data to the connected gui modul?

Would it be possible to additionally implement the tasks as an observable (subject)?
Every time the data changes in the task, an observer will be notified.

And the observer will be implemented as socket server....

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I need to push the question again.